# How to read large XML RAW from Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I'm pretty new to Linq to SQL & Linq to XML but have cobbled together some code together that put the XML results from a stored proc into an XElement. However, it's started failing, apparently now that the XML data is getting larger (2K+) and my .Parse is reading truncated XML (the XML data comes back in two rows). Before i start fumbling into the weeds using xmlReaders and all that, maybe i'm looking at this wrong and there are better approaches.

My exact problem is below, but i'm also curious about any standard Linq idioms for doing this type of thing.

---

The specific error i'm getting is

> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected
>   end of file while parsing Name has
>   occurred. Line 1, position 2034.

My C# code is something like this

```
XDocument orders = new XDocument(from b in db.GetUserOrders(userid)
 select XElement.Parse(b.XML_F52E5B62_58B1_21e2_B105_00805A49AB12));
```

The stored proc looks like

```
select * from orders where userid = @userid order by tscreated
for xml raw('order'), ROOT('orders')
```

The XML returned from the stored proc looks like

```
<orders>
  <order OrderId="123" UserId="bob" tscreated="2010-07-16T16:46:46.173">
    <morexml>
      <element1>
        <element2>abc</element2>
        <!--more stuff-->
      </element1>
    </morexml>
  </order>
  <!--lots more orders-->
</orders>
```

Comment: how large is the xml result?  Everything looks pretty normal so far...

Comment: Could be pretty large, ie. several K. It looks like the xml is coming back in two rows, so i probably need some sort of reader or iterator or something, but before fudging something together, i'm curious what the "right" way to do this is. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need to read all the rows and concatenate them.

Comment: I am having almost the exact same issue.  Any chance this was resolved and you can post the solution?

Comment: @EthanTowne, I had forgotten about this, so posted the answer I came up with. It's been a while (4.5 yrs), so my memory is fuzzy about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to update this with an answer, but given @EthanTowne's comment, I dug up what I'm doing in this code now:

```
var o = from ords in cfg.db.OsGetUserOrders(userid)
    select ords.XML_F52E5B62_58B1_21e2_B105_00805A49AB12;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("<orders>{0}</orders>", string.Join("", o.ToArray()));
XElement xe = XElement.Parse(sb.ToString());
```

Basically, the stored proc returns several `order` elements, and this code coverts them to an array then joins them into a string. Then I parse it into an XElement. There's probably a better way, and I'm open to other solutions.